# Populate existing array with json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function

i have little trouble in populating an existing array with json returned data.
Here is what i have

```
myarr=[];
function fillarr()
    {
    $.getJSON("test.php?c=10",function(data)
            {
            $.each(data, function(key, val)
                    {
                    myarr.push(data[val]);
                    }
                    });
            });
    }
```

My Problem is, that the array is emty outside the functions.
Please help.

Comment: what does the return data look like? is it an object literal or an array? and what is the scope of `myarr`?

Answer (score 1):

```
myarr=[];
function fillarr()
    {
    $.getJSON("test.php?c=10",function(data)
            {
            $.each(data, function(key, val)
                    {
                        myarr.push(val);
                        console.log(myarr); // you will myarr here, not out side
                    }
                    });
            });
      console.log(myarr); // wont get
    }
```

`myarr` get its content after ajax request complete and its take time. so `console` outside of $.getJSON execute before request complete.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it makes no diffrence.
The values are only available in the function and not outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
myarr=[];
function fillarr()
{
    $.getJSON("test.php?c=10", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            myarr.push(val);
        });
        doSomethingNowThatTheArrayIsActuallyPopulated();
    });
}

fillarr();

console.log(myarr); // This will print an empty array, it hasn't been populated yet.

function doSomethingNowThatTheArrayIsActuallyPopulated() {
    console.log(myarr); // This will print the array which now contains the json values
}
```

Comment: The returned data is an array.

Answer (score 0):

if the return data is an object, it's easier to do [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to push each value to the array.

```
function fillarr(){
    $.getJSON("test.php?c=10",function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            myarr.push(val);
        });
    });
}
```

if the return data is an array, [Array concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) would be faster

```
function fillarr(){
    $.getJSON("test.php?c=10",function(data){
        myarr = myarr.concat(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: the returned data is an array.

Comment: then concat would be better for the job

Comment: I've tried all your suggestion, thank you. the are working, but only inside the function. outside the function , the arra is still empty.

Comment: how can it be empty? where is this array declared?

Comment: ni the first line outside the function

Comment: That's because it hasn't fetched and processed the JSON yet, so the array is still empty. You need to use the getJSON callback to know when you can use the array.